# Unreleased xcdatamodel versions and lightweight migration

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

If I have multiple unreleased xcdatamodel versions between release A and release B, will lightweight migration still work once I release to the public if I delete the unreleased versions?

Here's a more discrete example:

```
xcdatamodel version 1.0  --> Release to public A
xcdatamodel version 1.1  --> unreleased (based on v1.0)
xcdatamodel version 1.2  --> unreleased (based on v1.1)
xcdatamodel version 1.3  --> Release to public B (based on v1.2)
```

I want to make sure that when I submit release B, users coming from release A will be migrated properly.  Or is this a completely terrible way to go about it?  I understand that if I didn't care about the data on my testing devices, I would just base xcdatamodel version 1.3 on version 1.0 and put everything new in that version - I just don't want to lose the data on my testing devices that have had versions of the app with v1.1 and v1.2 already on the device.

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is yes.  You can delete the intermediate development models before you release.  As mentioned by @Mike Weller, there are limits on what lightweight migration can do but if it's working in your development environment, then you already know that lightweight migration works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the format used for existing user data can be converted to the current format via automatic lightweight migration, it doesn't matter that you created internal, unreleased versions.

What you need to include in the released app: every version that any user might be using. In your case it looks like people would only have 1.0-formatted stores, so there's no need to include 1.1 or 1.2. If that's not the case-- i.e. if there's a user out there somewhere who might have version 1.1 or 1.2 data-- then you need to include them.

So, as long as the 1.0 --> 1.3 changes work with automatic lightweight migration **and** that no users have 1.1 or 1.2 format data, you could just delete the intermediate versions.

Comment: Thanks Tom!  That's exactly what I needed to know.  The only thing that I'm still confused about is how the migration would actually work if 1.1 and 1.2 were removed.  I imagined it worked by stepping from one "iteration" of the data model to the next, in sequence.  According to your answer, it must be more magical than that if it can figure out how to migrate 1.0->1.3 even if 1.1 and 1.2 have subsequently been deleted.  If you have any insight on this process, or know of an apple doc that explains it, I'd love to know.  Thanks again!

Comment: At run time, Core Data knows what the current model is. If automatic lightweight migration is enabled, it looks to see if any non-current model matches the existing persistent store. When it finds one, it compares that model to the current one to see if migration is possible. Models aren't cumulative-- there's only a current version and non-current versions.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I guess I got thrown off by xcode because when you create a new model version, it asks what previous version you want to base the new one off.  I assumed this had something to do with the migration process - I have been enlightened.  Thanks a lot, Tom!

Comment: @Tom Harrington - I know it's been a while since this was posted but how do you delete the intermediate versions? I've tried selecting and hitting delete as well as right clicking (delete is greyed) as well as removing it from the package in Finder - nothing appears to work. XCode 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Lightweight migration will only work with certain types of model changes. The best thing is to test this thoroughly. You can safely do the following:

- Add new optional attributes or relationships to an entity
- Add new required attributes to an entity with a default value
- Change an existing optional attribute to required but with a default value
- Rename an attribute or relationship or entity and specify the old name in the "Renaming ID" field of the core data utilities pane tab.

The [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) lists more operations, but again you should test all this.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the answer.  I think I lead you in the wrong direction a little.  I'm not really asking whether or not the changes in my various models are "migratable" - I'm positive they are.  I'm really more wondering if a user going from Release A to Release B in my example above will be migrated from v1.0->v1.1->v1.2->v1.3 when they upgrade, or if v1.1 and v1.2 are completely ignored somehow.  i.e. can I delete v1.1 and v1.2 of the model before I release, or should I leave them alone.